# How to shut down openwrt without corrupting file systems?

Tags: linux, openwrt

I have a small box running OpenWRT (it's actually a Wifi Pineapple). It has an internal file system on the microsd. If I plug in a USB drive with a formatted ext3 file system, then the drive is automatically mounted.

How do I safely turn it off? Does OpenWRT automatically flush all buffers and sync its filesystems so you can turn it off at any time? Or is something else going on?

Answer (score 22):

OpenWrt doesn't have a `shutdown -h/-r` command.

On Openwrt, one uses `reboot`, `halt` or `poweroff` commands instead.

Move to Ext4, should be save with shutdown.

Comment: ext4 is not some magic genie.  If ext4 is not cleanly unmounted it WILL be flagged dirty.